# Spring & Hibernate: Block user from writing

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I need to prevent a single user from writing to the Database, is there any possibility to achieve this without changing every occurrence of save or update? I thought like wrapping the hibernate session. What would you advise me to do?

thanks
Sebastian

Comment: Can you please show us an example of how do you write to DB (where do you obtain Hibernate session from, ...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up using an Hibernate Interceptor. If I implement onSave(), onDelete() and onFlushDirty() is there any possibility to circumvent this methods and write to the db? If not I'm pretty happy with this solution. Because as it turns out this user isn't allowed to read some fields neither.

Answer (score 2):

I'll recommend that you use a security framework such as Spring Security or Apache Shiro to implement cross-cutting security concerns at application level.

Comment: Agreed, sounds like you want a ROLE of sorts with method level security on writes where applicable.